# Is a pdf geospatial if the Adobe Reader Geospatial Location Tool doesn't write anything?

Tags: coordinates, pdf, geospatial-pdf

Does a PDF contain geographical coordinates if the Adobe Reader Geospatial Location Tool doesn't write anything?

I mean that I am moving the mouse over the pdf and no latitude and longitude values will show.

Does this mean there are no coordinates stored in the map?

Comment: I think so, but couldn't you just test it yourself? E.g. create a geospatial PDF and a non-geospatial PDF and compare the results? You can do both with ArcMap.

Comment: I don't know how to create those PDFs.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142403/

Answer (score 3):

When `Adobe Reader Geospatial Location Tool` **doesn't show** the *Latitude* and the *Longitude*, that means the geographical coordinates are **not** stored in the **pdf** map.

To convince yourself that your `Adobe Reader` is working well, please, use this **[pdf](http://www.avenza.com/sites/default/files/spatialpdf/US_County_Populations.pdf)**

After opening the **pdf**, you may go to `Edit/Analise/Geospatial Location Tool` and move the mouse cursor over the map. In the right-bottom corner you must to see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways for storing the geolocation info into PDF. One is called "Adobe Supplement to ISO 32000" while the other is "OGC GeoPDF Encoding Best Practice Version 2.2 (08-139r3)". The location tool of Acrobat Reader finds the coordinates if they are stored by using the ISO 32000 way but not necessarily if the other system is used. [Terrago toolbar](http://www.terragotech.com/products/terrago-toolbar) add-on can show also the GeoPDF (tm) coordinates. Gdalinfo utility can tell you if PDF has coordinates or not. You can also create geospatial PDF files with GDAL.

http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html

http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pdf.html

http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html